# How to generate sequential subsets of integers?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following start and end values:

```
start = 0
end = 54
```

I need to generate subsets of 4 sequential integers starting from `start` until `end` with a space of 20 between each subset. The result should be this one:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 24, 25, 26, 27, 48, 49, 50, 51
```

In this example, we obtained 3 subsets:

```
0, 1, 2, 3
24, 25, 26, 27
48, 49, 50, 51
```

How can I do it using `numpy` or `pandas`?

If I do `r = [i for i in range(0,54,4)]`, I get `[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```py
r = [j for i in range(0, 54, 24) for j in range(i, i + 4)]
print(r)
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 24, 25, 26, 27, 48, 49, 50, 51]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get you what you want:

```
j = 20
k = 4
result = [split for i in range(0,55, j+k) for split in range(i, k+i)]
print (result)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 24, 25, 26, 27, 48, 49, 50, 51]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [numpy.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) which returns an `ndarray` object containing evenly spaced values within a given range

```py
import numpy as np

r = np.arange(0, 54, 4)

print(r)
```

Result

```sh
[0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Numpy approach

You can use `np.arange` to generate number with a step value of `20 + 4`, where 20 is for space between each interval and 4 for each sequential sub array.

```
start = 0
end   = 54
out   = np.arange(0, 54, 24) # array([ 0, 24, 48]) These are the starting points
                             # for each subarray

step = np.tile(np.arange(4), (len(out), 1))
# [[0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3]
#  [0 1 2 3]]


res  = out[:, None] + step

# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [24, 25, 26, 27],
#        [48, 49, 50, 51]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with plane python:

```
rangeStart = 0
rangeStop = 54
setLen = 4
step = 20
stepTot = step + setLen
a = list( list(i+s for s in range(setLen)) for i in range(rangeStart,rangeStop,stepTot))
```

In this case you will get the subsets as sublists in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use numpy or pandas to do what you want. I achieved it with a simple while loop

```
num = 0
end = 54
sequence = []

while num <= end:
    sequence.append(num)
    num += 1
    if num%4 == 0: //If four numbers have been added
        num += 20
//output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 24, 25, 26, 27, 48, 49, 50, 51]
```